# Kohana routing does not match optional param

Tags: php, routes, kohana, kohana-3

I cant get a route with optional parameter to parse ID at the end. Here is my route:

```
Route::set('default', '<action>(/<id>)', array(
    'action' => '.*',
    'id' => '\d+'
))->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'MediaLibrary',
    'action' => 'index'
));
```

When I look at params, I get:

```
array(2) (
    "action" => string(7) "test/91"
    "controller" => string(12) "MediaLibrary"
)
```

However if I change the route to `<action>/(<id>)` it works. Id will be parsed without problem and action will change to `test` instead of `test/91`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because `action` param has catch-all regex, try to change it to `[a-z0-9]+`.

```
Route::set('default', '<action>(/<id>)',
    array(
        'action' => '[a-z0-9]+',
        'id'     => '\d+'
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'MediaLibrary',
        'action'     => 'index'
    ));
```